# show-paren-mode -- stay visible while inside the braces / brackets

Tags: emacs

Is there any custom modification that keeps the braces highlighted the entire time that the cursor is within the two braces?

The default behavior is to only highlight the braces momentarily and then it disappears once the cursor is inside the braces.

Comment: What do you want when you're inside nested braces?

Comment: The active braces should please be the ones closest to the cursor position.  However, if there is a way to have outer-lying braces appear in different colors a few layers deep, that would be awesome.  However, I would be very happy if just the braces closest to me are active.  I would certainly be welcome to suggestions because you are probably aware of options that I hadn't considered before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Higlight Parentheses mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightParentheses), which does exactly what you ask for in that response to Trey Jackson's comment.

[image: Highlight Parentheses mode example]

The colors are, of course, configurable.

Comment: Simple, but very effective.  It shines through the highlight current line (contrary to rainbow delimiters), and it indicates where the cursor is in relation to the active braces (including nesting).  I like it -- that's a keeper !!!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [hl-sexp](http://edward.oconnor.cx/elisp/hl-sexp.el) (available on MELPA). This highlights the innermost sexp that point is inside, making it easy to spot the brackets.

[image: current sexp highlighted]

(rainbow delimiters are also visible in this screenshot)

Comment: Thank you for the link -- I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the library [rainbow delimiters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters) might be what you're looking for. Might need some tweaking to get it to your taste.

Comment: I just installed it and set up different combinations for 9 nested levels and the unmatched; however, it gets trumped by highlight line.  Highlight the current line is one of my favorite features, and unless there is a way to let rainbow delimiters shine through, . . . .  Also, it doesn't appear to call attention to where the cursor is at any given moment - i.e., all braces are highlighted simultaneously throughout the document.  show-paren-mode and highlight-parentheses-mode (suggested by Inaimathi both shine through the highlight current line).  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I've decided to go with highlight-parentheses.el for the reasons cited above and also in the comment by me underneath the answer by `Inaimathi`.  I'm keeping rainbow delimiters installed, but not active, so that I can highlight all braces in the document whenever I need a birds-eye view.  Thank you very much for your help -- greatly appreciated !!!.